# button not disappearing when pack_forget is called in python

Tags: python, tkinter

So, when I create a label and try to use .pack_forget(), it does not disappear as I would like it to. I don't know how to fix it, so it would be great if someone could help, as it basically just blocks everything else from sight. I thought it was the anchor at first, but i tried removing it, and the same thing happened.

code related to the problem:

```
import random
from tkinter import *



def a():
    button_play['text'] = 'Play again?'
    button_play['command'] = new_game()
    button_play.pack_forget()
    # This is where it doesn't dissapear
    new_game()
    submit_button.pack()
    submit_button.place(relx=0.75, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

#   other buttons and functions
button_play = Button(window,
                     text='Play',
                     command=a,
                     font=('Comic Sans', 20),
                     bg='white',
                     fg='black')
button_play.pack()
button_play.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: have you tried adding `global button_play` to the beginning of your function?

Comment: When you set the command you call the `new_game` function. Remove the parentheses at the end (`button_play['command'] = new_game`).

Comment: You're adding the button with `place`, not `pack`.

Comment: Actually `button_play` is put by `place` layout manager because `button_play.place(...)` overrides `button_play.pack()`, so `button_play.pack_forget()` has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

```
it does not disappear as I would like it to
```

You're making it bad. No need to forget(), destroy(), etc. Just one widget will update.

Code:

```
import random
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

def a():
    button_play['text'] = 'Play again?'
    button_play['command'] = new_game
    
         
button_play = Button(text='Play',
                     command=a,
                     font=('Comic Sans', 20),
                     bg='white',
                     fg='black')

button_play.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
mainloop()
```

Screenshot play and play again:

[image]   [image]